# Rails 4 update data using xml and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to automaticly update data using a ajax call out of jquery.

When an object gets moved, this code is being executed:

This is my jquery code

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: "/devices/2328.xml",
data: '<device><name>test</name></device>',

  contentType: 'application/xml', // format of request payload
  dataType: 'html', // format of the response
  });
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def update
@device = Device.find(params[:id])
if @device.update_attributes(device_params)
  respond_with @device
else
  render :action => 'edit'
end
end

private
def device_params
  params.require(:device).permit(:name)
end
```

In my log I can see the request comming in, but nothing really happens, see at the bottom Completed 204 No Content
I'm also noticing that the value that I'm passing cannot be found at the parameters part of the log

```
Started PUT "/devices/2328.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-01 19:10:33 +0100
Processing by DevicesController#update as XML
Parameters: {"id"=>"2328"}

Device Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `devices`.* FROM `devices` WHERE `devices`.`id` = 2328  LIMIT 1
```

(0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
   Completed 204 No Content in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

I can't really figure out what is wrong.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: what is the result of `if @device.update_attributes(device_params)
  raise "updated #{@device}"
  respond_with @device
else

Comment: When I change the code you've added, I'm getting a runtime error
`RuntimeError (updated #<Device:0x00000002b6eca0>):`, this hash is filled with data that comes from the id. When I change it to params[:device], it houses nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `data: 'test'` parameters being passed through.  It might be a key/value pair problem.

Change `data: { 'device': { 'name': 'test' }}` in

```
$.ajax({ type: "PUT", url: "/devices/2328.xml", 
  data: { 'device': { 'name': 'test' }},
  contentType: 'application/xml', // format of request payload
  dataType: 'html', // format of the response
});
```

Comment: Hi Nate, I've tried the changes you proposed, but I'm now getting other errors:
`Started PUT "/devices/2328.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-01 21:01:59 +0100
Processing by DevicesController#update as XML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2328"}
  Device Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `devices`.* FROM `devices` WHERE `devices`.`id` = 2328 LIMIT 1
Completed 400 Bad Request in 5ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: device):
  app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:68:in `device_params'
  app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:44:in `update'
`

Comment: The name parameter did not appear in the logfiles

Comment: how about `data: { 'device': { 'name': 'test' }}`

Comment: Hi Nate, still no content and nothing in the params
`Started PUT "/devices/2328.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-01 21:39:59 +0100
Processing by DevicesController#update as XML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2328"}
  Device Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `devices`.* FROM `devices` WHERE `devices`.`id` = 2328 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Completed 204 No Content in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)`